# matplotlib quiver can not get its width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to plot vectors by using plt.quiver(), and my editor is Jupyer lab.
I have found a problem. If I try to get the quiver width, it would return None before the figure display.
But after the figure having displayed, the quiver width can be obtained normally.

Like this:
[image]

The first time I print q1.width, it returns None. But the second time it can work without problem.
How can I solve this problem?

(I am not a native English speaker, so if some sentences are not clear, I am very sorry about this.)

Comment: Copy paste the code from image. It will be better if someone wants to run it in their local machine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. The quiver width (or any other parameters) are only calculated when the figure is drawn.

Comment: I see! It seems that I have to find another method instead of using q1.width. Thanks!

Comment: Well, no, it just means that you need to draw the figure before being able to query the parameters.

Comment: oh yes, it is what I mean actually. Sorry I didn't express clearly.